# can i add progressive widget on another android or ios app screen using codename one?

Tags: codenameone

[image]I am making an application on codename one. i want one progressive widget which can call my application on another android and ios application screen. so how can I provide progressive widget of using codename one on another android and ios application?

I added diagramic representation what i want plz refer this an give the solution

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. Do you have a screenshot of what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: Above I added diagramic representation what i want plz refer this an give the solution

Answer (score 0):

Codename One doesn't integrate well as a widget into other apps. You can integrate an AAR into Codename One and work with a native widget (e.g. embed Google Maps into Codename One) but taking a Codename One app and embedding it into another application would be problematic.

One thing you can do is launch a Codename One app based on a URL scheme and then return to the original app by launching it via a URL scheme. This works on iOS and Android and we cover it in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/).